# How to calculate complexity of internal iterations

Tags: java, iteration, time-complexity

This is regarding identifying time complexity of a java program. If i've iterations like for or while etc, we can identify the complexity. But if i use java API to do some task, if it is internally iterating, i think we should include that as well. If so, how to do that.

Example :

```
          String someString = null;
          for(int i=0;i<someLength;i++){

          someString.contains("something");// Here i think internal iteration will happen, likewise how to identify time complexity          

}
```

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Internal operations in the Java APIs have their own time complexity based on their implementation. For example the `contains` method of the String variable runs with linear complexity, where the dependency is based on the length of your `someString` variable.

In short - you should check how inner operations work and take them into consideration when calculating complexity.

Particularly for your code the time complexity is something like O(N*K), where N is the number of iterations of your loop (`someLength`) and K is the length of your `someString` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that the internal iterations will add to your complexity. However, except in a fairly small number of cases, the complexity of API methods is not well documented. Many collection operations come with an upper bound requirement for all implementations, but even in such cases there is no guarantee that the actual code doesn't have lower complexity than required. For cases like `String.contains()` an educated guess is almost certain to be correct, but again there is no guarantee.

Your best bet for a consistent metric is to look at the source code for the particular API implementation you are using and attempt to figure out the complexity from that. Another good approach would be to run benchmarks on the methods you care about with a wide range of input sizes and types and simply estimate the complexity from the shape of the resulting graph. The latter approach will probably yield better results for cases where the code is too complex to analyze directly.